# Able to access shared files on Ubuntu from Windows only when I ping the IP from Ubuntu

Tags: networking, samba

I shared a folder from the Shared Options of the folder allowing guest access. If I try to open this folder (or my Ubuntu system) from my Win7 system using the IP or the hostname, I get an error. But if I ping my Win7 ip from my Ubuntu and then try accessing  Ubuntu IP over the network it suddenly starts working...but only for a short while or until the ping continues.

Note, however, that at this point opening my Ubuntu system using \\UbuntuSys from Win7 still doesn't work!

Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

All the symptoms you describe point to an IP address conflict within your network. Carefully check that no other computer has the same IP as either the Ubuntu system or the Windows box.

Comment: I checked. No duplicate IP. Also, my Ubuntu system is not showing up in the Wireless attached devices in my router settings page.

Comment: actually i see the mac address in the attached devices but no IP or system name.